# git merge vs rebase

Tags: git

Soy un no iniciado en git, y me surge una duda.

Tenemos un branch MASTER del proyecto en el que estoy desarrollando, y he abierto un branch para realizar cambios locales. Mientras tanto, en el branch MASTER se han realizado commits de otros miembros del proyecto.

Mi pregunta es, cual es el mejor método para incorporar esos cambios a mi branch sin necesidad de actualizar el branch MASTER?

Y una vez terminado mis cambios, como paso mis cambios al branch MASTER? lo pregunto porque en algún caso hemos perdido commits del branch MASTER, desconozco que hicimos mal, pero se perdieron cambios por el camino.

Actualmente siempre utilizamos merge en las dos vías  MASTER -> mi-rama y mi-rama -> MASTER. Pero como dije antes, durante ese proceso alguna vez se perdieron commits por el camino, y desconocemos el por qué.

Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Los pasos a seguir serian:

```
git checkout tuRamaNueva
git merge master (resuelves todos los conflictos)
```

En caso de querer aplicar tu evolutivo a la rama principal:

```
git checkout master
git merge tuRamaNueva
```

Realizando estos pasos evitaras tener que resolver los conflictos en la rama master.

**El titulo no dice mucho de la explicación que das, se aconseja usar merge y mas en tu caso ya que los cambios están en el servidor se suele utilizar rebase para cambios en local.**

Comment: @CamiloBernal revisalo de nuevo estaba editando ^^

Comment: Nosotros siempre hemos utilizado merge para incorporar cambios, pero haciendo esto de una u otra forma hemos perdido commits en la rama principal por el camino, desconozco el motivo.

Comment: Cuando habéis perdido cambios ha sido cuando algún push ha tenido conflictos? Suele ser el motivo principal cuando se pierden los cambios en git. En la resolución de conflictos hay que estar alerta para evitar este tipo de errores.

Comment: No, no ,se perdieron commits de archivos que no se tocaron en una de las ramas, a lo mejor (peor) hacer merge de una rama sin hacer update o cosas así.

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro pero creo que no te deja hacer merge sin antes haber hecho un pull. Con los push lo se seguro pero con el merge no estoy al 100%